# Application.OnKey will not assign F1?

Tags: excel, vba, shortcut

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Application.OnKey "^+{F1}", "RunMe"
End Sub

Public Sub RunMe()
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

It seems "{F1}" cannot be used in assigning a shortcut to a procedure, at least not using the Application.OnKey method.

- Tried F1 alone and in various combinations with modifier keys.
- Tried in VBAProject > Module1 and in ThisWorkbook > Workbook_Open as
  Private Sub and Public Sub.
- Tried specifying procedure as "Module.Procedure".
- Tried the (supposedly) assigned procedure as Private Sub and Public
  Sub.

Replacing F1 with F2 or F3 works fine, but I need F1, preferably Ctrl+Shift+F1, whose default assignment "Toggle Full Screen."

Did the F1 key become reserved by Microsoft?

Comment: Interesting, it seems that you cannot re-assign Ctrl-Shift-F1. Though `Application.OnKey "^{F1}", "RunMe"` resp.  `Application.OnKey "+{F1}", "RunMe"` is working.

Comment: @Storax You are correct. I was spent when I posted and my best recollection from the day's testing blur was that I could not bind F1 with any modifier. Re-testing now shows both Ctrl+F1 and Shift+F1 assign as intended via Application.OnKey. Thank you for your input.

Comment: For various reasons, such not giving up default shortcut keys assignments, and how I re-assign other function keys with Application.OnKey, I really wanted <Ctrl>+<Shift> for the modifier. Since you confirm that <Ctrl>+<Shift>  is not available with F1, after considering what default functions I will lose, I have decided to amend my code conventions on modifier keys and thus go with simply <Ctrl>+<F1>. I'll mark yours as the answer. FYI: losing defaults by re-mapping many shortcuts, one can see what's being lost via the most robust list I've seen at https://www.excelcampus.com/shortcuts/.